# Jenkins github webhooks doesn't trigger my pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, github-webhook

I have a problem with my job starting automatically when a webhook from github arrives at the jenkins server.

I have a private organization account on github. A webhook like http://MY_JENKINS_SERVER/github-webhook/ has been added to the required project

On the Jenkins side, a pipeline was created with the checkboxes checked:

- GitHub project
- GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling
  And also the ssh link to the repository is indicated in the Pipeline section.

Until recently everything worked. But then for testing, I had to uncheck "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling". A few days later, I checked this box again, but my pipeline no longer starts automatically, even after manually starting it.

In the jenkins logs, I see the message "Skipped [my_pipeline] because it doesn't have a matching repository.", but I didn't change the project references.

I have been struggling with this problem for 3 days already, I have gone through the floor of the Internet and I am already in despair. Help me please

I tried changing the token, ssh keys, links to the project

Answer (score 0):

webhook only allowed HTTPS. I am also faced with this issue. try HTTPS instead of HTTP

In order for GitHub to send webhook payloads, your server needs to be accessible from the **Internet** like public IP. We also highly suggest using SSL so that we can send encrypted payloads over **HTTPS**

Webhook format : https://Your Public IP/github-webhook/

Note: Jenkins Server IP needs to be public IP then only you can receive webhook.

Comment: That is, do I need to specify HTTPS instead of HTTP in github in webhooks?

Comment: Yes. Webhook only allows the secure link.

Comment: But I noticed that the webhook makes my pipelines work, which are located in public repositories, although my jenkins server is on http